# Pass line break to Long Text Field from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud

I have a Journey in Marketing Cloud that is creating records in an object in the Sales & Service Cloud from data stored in an SFMC Data Extension. That object has a long text field that I sometimes have to use and I would like to be able to pass things across to make the long text field more readable.

I have tried something like the following code when inserting records to the Journey but this did not display as hoped in the Salesforce Object.

```
Concat("Example: ", @field1, "<br>", "Example: ", @field2, "<br><br>")
```

Is it possible to do anything like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using HTML, you should use newline and carriage return:

```
Concat("Example: ", @field1, "\r\n", "Example: ", @field2, "\r\n")
```

Comment: Since he wanted a double linebreak it should be `Concat("Example: ", @field1, "\r\n", "Example: ", @field2, "\r\n\r\n")` details Lukas, details ;)

Comment: Commenting here in case still if someone searching this... `Char(10)` https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307048/pass-a-line-break-to-a-long-text-area-in-createsalesforceobject-function?noredirect=1&lq=1