# Pass a line break to a Long Text Area in CreateSalesforceObject function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am creating a new Opportunity in Sales Cloud using AMPscript and I need to insert line breaks in the Description field (Long Text Area, 32000).

This solution did not work: [Pass line break to Long Text Field from Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278277/pass-line-break-to-long-text-field-from-journey-builder)

Also tried the following:

`concat("grade: ",RequestParameter("Grade"),"\n","comment: ",RequestParameter("Comment"))`

`concat("grade: ",RequestParameter("Grade"),"\\n","comment: ",RequestParameter("Comment"))`

`concat("grade: ",RequestParameter("Grade"),"&lt;br/&gt;","comment: ",RequestParameter("Comment"))`

`concat("grade: ",RequestParameter("Grade"),"<br/>","comment: ",RequestParameter("Comment"))`

All of those are displaying as text since I am passing them as a string, what am I missing here?

Comment: %%=concat("grade: ",RequestParameter("Grade"),char(10,1),"comment: ",RequestParameter("Comment"))=%%  -- Hi @zuzannamj Does this help?

Comment: Is there are request somewhere to make this approach more user-friendly? I would like to upvote that request. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it, but according [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005aROQAY) post it's `\r\n`

**EDIT**:
Correct way seems to be `%%=UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Opportunity','ID','Description',Concat('new', CHAR(10), CHAR(13), 'line'))=%%`

Comment: Thanks - already tried it but couldn't get it to work

Comment: @zuzannamj found a solution, please see the edit on response

Comment: Yay, thank you Mateusz :-) Actually `CHAR(10)` was enough`.

Answer (score 1):

**Moving from comment to answer:**

I have tested in my instance. The answer by @Mateusz also works. And this also works.

```
%%[
Set @character = char(10,2)
Set @newline = concat("New",@character,"Line")
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Opportunity','0061t000002axd0AAA','Description',@newline)
]%%
```

Let me know if this works for you.