# Line breaks in description field (From Journey builder - Create task activity)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, tasks, activities, line-break

Within journey builder I create task activities and push this to Sales Cloud.
The text we enter in the 'description' (long text field) ends up in one line in Sales Cloud, which makes it unclear.

Our default way of enter a description is: *Contact - Name: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FirstName"}} {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."LastName"}}. From url: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FormUrl"}}.*

Tried this [Pass line break to Long Text Field from Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278277/pass-line-break-to-long-text-field-from-journey-builder?rq=1). Adjusted the description into: *Contact - Name: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FirstName"}} {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."LastName"}}. "\r\n" From url: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FormUrl"}}.*

This did not work. Am I using this line break in the wrong way? Or do I suppose to use this elsewhere?

Comment: I think you've lost your line breaks in rendering your question. Are you saying you've changed it to
Contact - Name: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FirstName"}} {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."LastName"}}.\r\nFrom url: {{Event."APIEvent-xxx"."FormUrl"}}

Comment: @JarrettBush I see, adjusted my question! Well, I used "\r\n" where I want to have an enter.

Comment: i think a solution can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307048/pass-a-line-break-to-a-long-text-area-in-createsalesforceobject-function - try char(10)

Comment: @JonasLamberty this is done by AMP script, but you can't use AMP script within a text field description (in task in journey). Already raised a new idea https://clicktime.symantec.com/3PHXUCNUFmcfz2R8ZkpZPgU6H2?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftrailblazer.salesforce.com%2FideaView%3Fid%3D0874V000000UKCWQA4

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this works for your context. Here is what I tried and worked.
Build a query to concatenate the fields with char(13) where you want to have a line break and store it in a description field in your DE then assign it to the task description in journey builder.
e.g

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('Contact - Name: ',FirstName,' ',LastName,char(13),'From URL',Fromurl) ...
```